# GroupBy and compares the elements with quantile of groups in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I'm a newbie on Python and Pandas. I have a CSV with Date and Temp values over 30 years and for my purposes I calculate the quantile for each groupBy Month.

```
input_file = pd.read_csv("DailyMax_lat-14_lon35.csv")
sQ = data.groupby(['Month']).quantile(0.5)['TmaxScaled']

print(sQ)
Month
1     297.977336
2     298.190348
3     298.433919
4     298.580322
5     298.221629
6     296.736598
7     296.463704
8     298.701436
9     302.380452
10    304.102163
11    303.562688
12    299.231298
```

Now I want to split the DataFrame in two DataFrames with smaller values and bigger values respectively than the quantile calculated, for each Month.

Can you help me?

```
print(input_file) is 

   Year  Month  Day  TmaxScaled
0      1980      1    3  296.941457
1      1980      1    4  296.978455
2      1980      1    5  296.654368
3      1980      1    6  296.732218
4      1980      1    7  297.468730
5      1980      1    8  298.330566
6      1980      1    9  297.844157
7      1980      1   10  297.228007
8      1980      1   11  296.916066
9      1980      1   12  297.247884
10     1980      1   13  297.851888
11     1980      1   14  298.854523
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need `transform`

```
df['New']=df.groupby(['Month'])['TmaxScaled'].transform(lambda x :x.quantile(0.5) )
df1,df2=df.loc[df.TmaxScaled>df.New],df.loc[df.TmaxScaled<=df.New]
df1
Out[43]: 
    Year  Month  Day  TmaxScaled         New
4   1980      1    7  297.468730  297.237946
5   1980      1    8  298.330566  297.237946
6   1980      1    9  297.844157  297.237946
9   1980      1   12  297.247884  297.237946
10  1980      1   13  297.851888  297.237946
11  1980      1   14  298.854523  297.237946
df2
Out[44]: 
   Year  Month  Day  TmaxScaled         New
0  1980      1    3  296.941457  297.237946
1  1980      1    4  296.978455  297.237946
2  1980      1    5  296.654368  297.237946
3  1980      1    6  296.732218  297.237946
7  1980      1   10  297.228007  297.237946
8  1980      1   11  296.916066  297.237946
```

Answer (score 1):

Compute `sQ` as you've already done:

```
sQ = df.groupby(['Month']).quantile(0.5)['TmaxScaled'].item()

print(sQ)
297.2379455
```

Now, perform a `groupby` and split `df` into groups:

```
df_dict = {k : g for k, g in df.groupby(df.TmaxScaled > sQ)}
```

`df_dict[True]` returns a DataFrame whose values are over the quantile, and vice versa, for `df_dict[False]`:

```
df_dict[True]
    Year  Month  Day  TmaxScaled
4   1980      1    7  297.468730
5   1980      1    8  298.330566
6   1980      1    9  297.844157
9   1980      1   12  297.247884
10  1980      1   13  297.851888
11  1980      1   14  298.854523
```

```
df_dict[False]    
   Year  Month  Day  TmaxScaled
0  1980      1    3  296.941457
1  1980      1    4  296.978455
2  1980      1    5  296.654368
3  1980      1    6  296.732218
7  1980      1   10  297.228007
8  1980      1   11  296.916066
```

Note that this preserves order within groups.

Comment: I receive this error with first instruction 

ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

Comment: @Darkwilmore Did you add the `.item()` at the end of the sQ calculation?! It won't work otherwise.

Comment: @Darkwilmore if that doesn't work, try: `sQ = df.groupby(['Month']).quantile(0.5)['TmaxScaled'].iloc[0].item()`

Comment: @Darkwilmore Thanks for the follow up. It seemed like your actual data was returning something else. Meanwhile, for your sample data, the original code worked for me. Which answer are you using?